# How to monitor and analyze screenshots from multiple Raspberry Pi kiosks?

Tags: kiosk, screenshot

I have setup with 10 Raspberry Pi kiosks that run Chromium in full screen, and that works great most of the time.

To make sure all monitors are working ok they have cronjob that sends screenshots via email twice per day.

But that is a lot of emails to go trough each day, and most of the time all of them work ok, so it is really tedious going trough 10 screenshots twice daily.

First idea is to simply display images (two groups of ten images) from last two runs that are sent to central server. I can setup so that screenshots are saved into custom folders, and then some simple html could show it. I have no idea how to do html and display part.

Other more advanced idea would be to have some image recognition app that would "look" at photos and know if chrome is running and showing something or if it is an empty desktop. Because we have always same colour header on the screen that would work simply by looking at one area and checking if it is green (chromium running) or beige (wallpaper from desktop).

If you have any ideas or implementation tips please share them.

Comment: What image format are you using?

Comment: I am inclined to say that this task is completely unrelated to the raspberry pi (and thus off-topic).

Comment: You're going the most complicated route from the beginning. Why don't you try out something simpler first? E.g. monitor status of chromium process. If it happens that chromium process is still running, but the window is dead, you could use `wmctrl -l` to list all open windows. Would that help?

Comment: @bex I'm using png and jpeg.

Comment: @xx77aBs wmctrl doesn't work over remote ssh shell.

Comment: I agree with @Ghanima that this is not really a pi specific question. However, have a look at these answers, they should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python

Comment: @valentt It should be possible to run it even over remote ssh, but why do you need to do that? Just set it up so it runs inside of started X session locally and reports back if something's wrong.